# Dynamic creation class field on ngOnInit() in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, ngoninit

I try to dynamic create variables in class to store values and use it in ngModel and other placese. 
I know, that I can assign value to variables in ngOnInit() like this

```
export class Component implements OnInit{
   name: string;
   ngOnInit(){
       this.name = 'John Doe';
   }
}
```

But I have some problem -  I get my fields from server API and don't know what and how many items I get. I can only parsing server response and assign value to new variables after get it.

I can't do it like this (TS2540: Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant or a read-only property.)

```
export class Component implements OnInit{
   ngOnInit(){
       name = 'John Doe';
   }
}
```

How can I assign new fields to my class in ngOnInit() or maybe in other place? (I think I can do it in constructor, but documentation say i shouldn't use it with Observable call to API and other difficult things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to accomplish that:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this['prop'] = 'value';
}
```

Here is a link to a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-class-props

Comment: Thank you for answer and live code, i forgot try [] assign! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an indexer to the class to be able to use any property name and not get a compiler error:

```
export class Component {
    [name: string]: any;
    ngOnInit(){
        this["name"] = 'John Doe';
        this.nameaa = "dd"
    }
}
```

You should take care though, this means you can misspell   property names and the compiler will not issue any error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and attention about misspell property names